# custom field in calendar entry office365

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365

We have an office365 setup and use the mail and calendar API to ingrate with our enviremenet.

Is it possible to add a custom field to calendar entry and be able to access and update via the [calendar API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#create-events)?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the data extension API to store custom data in a message, event, or contact of the user's account.

Here is an example that to create extension when create an appointment:

```
POST: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events
authorization: bearer {token}
content-type: application/json

{ 
 "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
  },
  "Start": {
      "DateTime": "2016-09-06T18:00:00",
      "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "End": {
      "DateTime": "2016-09-06T18:00:00",
      "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },

  "Extensions": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension",
      "ExtensionName": "Com.Contoso.Referral",
      "CompanyName": "Wingtip Toys",
      "ExpirationDate": "2015-12-30T11:00:00.000Z",
      "DealValue": 10000,
      "TopModels": [
        3001,
        4002,
        5003
      ],
      "TopSalespersons": [
        "Dana Swope",
        "Fanny Downs",
        "Randi Welch"
      ]
    }]

}
```

Get the extension on a exist object:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{eventId}/extensions('{extensionId}')
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{eventId}/extensions('Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.Com.Contoso.Referral')
```

More detail about this API, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/extensions-rest-operations#using-the-data-extensions-rest-api).

Comment: I wondering is there any similar for Sharepoint 2010 Calendar integration with Outlook 2010? I want to exposes any custom columns directly within Outlook 2010.